# Dos resultados misma columna

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla **compañías** con la columnas **id** y **nombre**. Y otra tabla **operaciones** con las columnas **envia_id**, **recibe_id**.
Quiero obtener los resultados **nombre** de **envia_id** y **recibe_id**. 
¿Y como obtengo los dos diferentes resultados en php?

```
SELECT
companias.id, companias.nombre, operaciones.envia_id, 
operaciones.recibe.id
INNER JOIN companias
ON operaciones.recibe_id=companias.id

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH) ) {
 echo "
   <tr>
   <td>$row[nombre]</td>
   <td>$row[nombre]</td>
   </tr>
 ";
}
```

Así consigo el nombre de quien recibe, ahora necesito que aparezca el nombre de quien envía.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/146834/edit)  colocando la consulta SQL que estás usando, y no olvides de poner la etiqueta del DBMS específico: ¿MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql, ...? Gracias.

Comment: O bien haces dos query para cada consulta y después con PHP utilizas los datos, o haces un `JOIN` de MySQL para unir las dos tablas y devolver y un solo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu tabla donde esta `id y nombre` se llama `usuarios` y que la otra tabla se llama `envios`, la siguiente query debería funcionar.

```
select envia.nombre, recibe.nombre 
from usuarios as u 
join envios as envia on u.id = envia.envia_id 
join envios as recibe on u.id = recibe.recibe_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se requiere hacer un doble `JOIN` entre las tablas `operaciones` y `companias`, uno para el que envía y otro para el que recibe.

Dado que vas a tener que usar dos veces el campo `nombre` de la tabla `companias`, una vez para el emisor y otra vez para el receptor, deberás usar un alias para diferenciarlas y luego poder leerlas de forma distinta.

La consulta sería entonces así:

```
SELECT 
    e.id, 
    e.nombre emisor, 
    r.nombre receptor, 
    o.envia_id, 
    o.recibe.id 
FROM operaciones o 
INNER JOIN companias e ON o.envia_id=e.id
INNER JOIN companias r ON o.recibe_id=r.id
```

Luego, para imprimir los datos, usarás los nombres de alias de las columnas, en este caso, `emisor` y `receptor`:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH) ) {
 echo "
   <tr>
   <td>$row["emisor"]</td>
   <td>$row["receptor"]</td>
   </tr>
 ";
}
```

**NOTA:** Si no vas a usar las columnas `envia_id` y `recibe_id` para mostrarlas por pantalla, no es necesario que las pongas en el `SELECT`.